# Rails 4: Use best_in_place gem with DataTables using server-side processing

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables, best-in-place

I am looking for a way of [best_in_place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) gem and [jQuery DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) plugin.

My DataTable loads data via Ajax and I can not find any resources explaining how to implement [best_in_place](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place). Can anyone share an example of how to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you seen this doc: http://bernatfarrero.com/in-place-editing-with-javascript-jquery-and-rails-3/

Comment: No I did not see that and I think this will help me. I was trying to create user-editable fields by using best_in_place in document which generates data requested by ajax, but this was not working…I can return regular HTML and that works just fine. Thank you